# std::string treated as cv::String in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, namespaces, visual-studio-2019

I've a  C++20 console project in Visual Studio 19 with a Release configuration and a /MT flag.
I am explicitly specifying namespaces for types in my projects.
When I create

```
std::string Foo,
```

it creates std::string type. So far so good.
However, when I create

```
std::vector <std::string> Bar,
```

it creates a `std::vector<cv::String>` type instead, which leads to undesired consequences.
The cv namespace is comming from OpenCV4. Not only its from a different namespace, the type itself starts with capital 'S'.
I don't have any "using namespace" or any other "using"s anywhere in my projects.

Any ideas?

I've tried to use 'using namespace std' right before the line, just in case, but, as expected, it didn't work.

I've expected

```
std::vector <std::string> Bar
```

to create a

```
std::vector <std::string>
```

type, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sidequestion: What are the _"undesired consequences"_?

Comment: This is why it is important and advised to read the documentation. Being able to find and read the corresponding documentation is vital part of software development.

Comment: By undesired consequences I meant different behaviour than with std::string. I've read the answer below that says this is basically alias. However, char * foo = &*(bar.begin() ); compiles inside an empty project, and were failing within an opencv project.
I blamed it on opencv too early, cause I thought the problem was a missing overload function for a const type. However, there was no such overload (for obvious reasons) for std::string anyway, so it's my bad.

Comment: It's not rly `char * foo = &*(bar.begin() )` strictly speaking, but was a `const char* iter = &*(foo.begin()->begin());` , since the string is inside a vector. And if anyone wants to know why would anyone do such an unholy c++ act - I wanted to do some address  comparisons by increasing iterator and comparing it with the iterator that points to the end of vector. 

Turns out its undefined behaviour, even if you never ever dereference it, and is forbidden. Turns out, doing it with pointers, **is also undefined behaviour**.


I probably should spend some time by reading the standard.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo it does answer the question, I've just forgot to mark it as such. Sorry, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cv::String` and `std::string` are actually the same thing.

From `opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp`:

```cpp
namespace cv {
typedef std::string String;
}
```

You can validate that with:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::string, cv::String>, "");
```